# Cannot convert a pointer to a struct to a int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

I'm trying to build a memory manager for my operating system. However, when I add a pointer to the next node property of the first heap item, it doesn't work. I suspect it cannot convert a pointer to a heap item to a unsigned int pointer.

Constants

```
#define MEMORY_BLOCK_FREE 0
#define MEMORY_BLOCK_USED 1
#define MEMORY_BLOCK_TAIL 2
```

Memory Block Struct

```c
typedef struct
{
    u32* addr;
    u32 size;
    u8 state;
    u32* next_block;
} memory_block;
```

Add function

```c
u32* add_block(u32 size)
{
    memory_block* cblock = &head;
    while (1)
    {
        if (cblock->state == MEMORY_BLOCK_TAIL)
        {
            break;
        }
        cblock = (memory_block*)cblock->next_block;
    }
    u32* addr = cblock->addr;
    cblock->size = size;
    cblock->state = MEMORY_BLOCK_USED;
    memory_block next;
    next.state = MEMORY_BLOCK_TAIL;
    next.addr = (u32*)(addr + size);
    cblock->next_block = (u32*)&next;
}
```

Comment: `addr + size` is suspicious.  Explain what function parameter `u32 size` represents.  Size in bytes?

Comment: I want to turn ```addr + size``` into a pointer. u32 is defined as ```unsigned int```. u32 is 32 bits, or 4 bytes.

Comment: Let's try again.  Does `add_block(1)` make for a 4 bytes block, a 1 byte block or what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I didn't understand. ```addblock(x)``` allocates a block with x bytes.

Comment: `next.addr = (u32*)(addr + size);` adds `size*4` to the address - pointer addition. I would not call that "`addblock(x)` allocates a block with x bytes."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Then how do I convert the pointer (addr+size) to a u32 pointer?

Comment: Suggest using a rounded up quotient of  size/4.  `(u32*)((addr +  3)/4);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216991/discussion-between-mike-and-chux-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 0):

memory_block next;

It is a wrong code.
Try this

```
memory_block *next;
next = malloc(sizeof(memory_block));
```

Comment: the compiler says 'new' is undeclared. I didn't make this clear in the begining, but I'm writing this as part of an operating system. It doesn't contain lots of refrences you'd usually be able to find in c.

Comment: In c programming, use malloc function.

Comment: No, im trying to implement my own malalloc function for my operating system. This is part of it. Also, do you know how to do the @ thing to reply to people with a space in their username. It's not working on stack for me.